# Remove dulicate rows using SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know if there is a way to remove duplicate values from a table. The key 'distinct' will fetch us the unique rows however if one value differs in a column, it wont. so just wanted to know if this can be achieved by any means. Hope the below example will help.

For example : In the below table there are two entries for Emp_ID 1234 with two different priorities. my output should consider the higher priority row alone.  Is it possible?

```
My table
+---------+------+--------+-------+
| Employee_ID| priority  | gender |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| 1234       |   1       | F      |
| 1234       |   10      | F      |
| 5678       |    2      | M      |
| 5678       |   25      | M      |
| 9101       |   45      | F      |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Output

```
+---------+------+--------+-------+
| Employee_ID| priority  | gender |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| 1234       |    1      | F      |
| 5678       |    2      | M      |
| 9101       |   45      | F      |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Try to use SELECT DISTINCT and MAX() referred to prioriti field.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139444

Comment: I Did. but select distinct will only remove duplicates which contains same values in all the columns. In my table the employee id 1234 contains two different values in the priority column hence it will not be considered as duplicate rows.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE
FROM Table t
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Employee_ID FROM Table WHERE Employee_ID = t.Employee_ID AND priority < t.Priority)
```

That is if you really want to remove them from the table. The Exists part can also be used in a select query to leave the values in the Original table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Employee_ID FROM Table WHERE Employee_ID = t.Employee_ID AND priority > t.Priority)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have tried using rank over partition and that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Employee_ID,max(priority) as priority,gender
from table
group by Employee_ID,gender
```

Comment: Thanks. Have used the similar logic and it worked :)